# Load same instance of a component in another component onClick in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components `smallViewComponent.jsx` and `fullViewComponent.jsx`.  In smallViewComponent.jsx, there are 3 instances of `<AbcComp>`.

So, the requirement is how to get these `<AbcComp>` instance on button click  `loadInstance()` and render the different instances of `<AbcComp>` in `fullViewComponent.jsx`.

## smallViewComponent.jsx

```
import AbcComp from './..'

 this.state = {
   cmpInstance = ['component1','component2','component3'];
 }
  
    
    render (){
       return (
               <div>
                   this.state.cmpInstance.map((e, index) => 
                        return (
                              //'component1','component2','component3' instance of AbcComp 
                            <AbcComp key={e} btnProps={e}/>  
                                                             
                         )       
              </div>
       )
    }
```

## AbcComp.jsx

```
render(){
       // based on btnProps some diffrent color is added here
      return (<div><Button className={this.props.btnProps}/></div>) 
 }
```

## fullViewComponent.jsx

```
loadInstance =() => {
  let cmpInstance = ['component1','component2','component3'];
   return cmpInstance[(Math.random() * cmpInstance .length) | 0]
}

render (){ 
       <button onClick={(e) => this.loadInstance()}></button>
     // dynamically load 'component1','component2','component3' instance of AbcComp below.
        <AbcComp /> 
}
```

Comment: so you have 3 instances of component A, you want to show a specific one in Component B depend on the button click ?

Comment: You could render `smallViewComponent` in `fullViewComponent` conditionally, as the instances of `AbcComp` is rendered in `smallViewComponent`